# How to respond to someone being late with a favor

Tags: family, instant-messaging

A relative of mine is doing me a favor. I didn't ask him for it, he offered it, but I'm genuinely happy that he wants to do it for me. He promised me to do it this week, but today he sent me a message telling me that he didn't have time this week due to some stuff going on in his office.

I'm completely fine with that, it really isn't something urgent and in the end he's doing me a favor, so I'm sure not going to complain if it takes some time. The problem is that I don't know how to word this properly.

---

**My goal:** I'd like to communicate to him that it's really fine if it takes some time and that I really appreciate his effort, without pressuring him or anything like that. Ideally someone would make an example how such a message could look like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a phrasing request. On this site we are focusing on helping people with their interpersonal interactions. You know what you want to achieve and how to achieve it already. We can't write your messages for you.

Comment: @Ontamu When you say "You know what you want to achieve and how to achieve it already" that isn't correct.  The OP knows what he wants to achieve, letting his relative know that it's fine that the favor will take a while.  He does **not** know how to achieve it.  That's the question.  Yes, it's a "phrasing question", but isn't phrasing literally an inter-personal skill?

Comment: @DaveG this is a good question to post on the meta. But OP knows he needs to respond, that it isn't urgent and that he is receiving a favor and he isn't going to complain or demand anything. That is the interpersonal part. How can we give a meaningful answer if he should say "Oh yeah, no problem" or "Sure, whenever you can is fine" it is meaningless and opinion based.